# Updating a record with an average of a column

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

I'm looking to find the average of a column where status=0 and update it onto another record into that table.
This is the query i'm attempting to use.

```
UPDATE mc25778 set balance=(AVG(balance WHERE status=0)) WHERE username="Average"
```

I get this error when trying to perform this task:

```
   Err] 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE status=0)) WHERE username="Average"' at line 1
```

Any ideas how I can sort this out?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can join the table with a subquery which separately calculate the average for every username,

```
UPDATE  mc25778 a
        INNER JOIN 
        (
            SELECT  username, AVG(balance) avg_bal
            FROM    mc25778 
            WHERE   status = 0
            GROUP   BY username
        ) b ON a.username = b.username
SET     a.balance = b.avg_bal
WHERE   a.username = 'Average'
```

**UPDATE 1**

It looks like you want to calculate the total average for all records having `status = 0` and the result of it will be updated on the record of `Average`

```
UPDATE  mc25778 a
        CROSS JOIN
        (
            SELECT  AVG(balance) avg_bal 
            FROM    mc25778 
            WHERE   status = 0
        )  b
SET     a.balance = b.avg_bal
WHERE   a.username = 'Average'
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/393b3/1)

Comment: hm... actually it says Affected rows: 0! I was looking in the wrong area haha. So it doesnt work :/

Comment: can you give sample records with your desired result please? `:)`

Comment: http://imgur.com/nMAvyev Alright, so here it shows the records in the table, i'm looking to update the 'average' username one to the average of all of the balances which have status = 0, Sorry for the confusion!

Comment: Okay worked like a charm and im certain! Thanks so much for your efforts :)

Comment: I want to do similar thing in MONGODB

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
Declare @avg decimal(10,2)
Set @avg=(SELECT AVG(balance) FROM mc25778 WHERE status = 0)
UPDATE mc25778 set balance=@avg WHERE username="Average"
```